# Columns not working in both Bootstrap 3 and 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up a new internal web page using bootstrap (both versions 3.3.6 and 4.0.0-alpha.6) columns, but for some reason they don't show up in Internet Explorer 11 (company-mandated). Instead of columns, the text is stacked vertically (see examples).

I have tried everything from complex code to the simple code I have attached to this question. Nothing has worked. I have also looked at every single web page I could find on this, and likewise nothing has worked. I have also tried using xs, sm, md, lg and xl column sizes, and they don't make any difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Test 4</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">lg-4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">lg-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">lg-3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">lg-3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">lg-3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">variable</div>
  <div class="col-3">variable</div>
  <div class="col-3">variable</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

The above code results in:

lg-4

lg-4

lg-3

lg-3

lg-3

variable

variable

variable

Instead of:

lg-4     lg-4     lg-3     lg-3     lg-3

variable     variable     variable

Comment: where close tag for `container-fluid`? you can't put a container into another container...

Comment: can you create js fiddle, for example, to faster help?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Grid System allows 12 columns across a page.
In order to avoid using all the 12 columns individually we can split the columns into sub columns as per our requirements.
However we need to ensure that the sub columns always sums up to 12 and never exceed 12 or else the content switches on to the next line.
So perform appropriate changes in your code as per the above concept and apart from  that to support the grid system in IE 11 consider including the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

In order to have further knowledge about grid system visit the following link : 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the sample I gave there are less than 12 columns per each row.

Answer (score 0):

Boy, is my face red ...

I closed the browser, cleared the cache, and went back in ... and it worked fine.

Live and learn ... sorry for the wasted time ...

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">Column 1-a</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">Column 1-b</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">Column 1-b</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">Column 1-b</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This made no difference - I tried it and got the same results.

Comment: I always used it if it always worked. Check if you have a good connection to the file